# I can't get to modify my static variable in java

Tags: java, recursion

You give a grid (4x4 here). you need to find out the total no of unique paths from (0,0) to (4,4). main() call a function pathify for this. It finds the possible "next steps" and calls it again. When (4,4) is reached noOfPaths++; is supposed to execute. This doesn't happen and I can't find the problem.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class NoOfPaths {
        static int xRows = 4; 
        static int yColumns = 4;
        static int noOfPaths = 0;

        /*A robot is located in the upper-left corner of a 4×4 grid. 
         * The robot can move either up, down, left, or right, 
         * but cannot go to the same location twice. 
         * The robot is trying to reach the lower-right corner of the grid. 
         * Your task is to find out the number of unique ways to reach the destination.
         **/

        static ArrayList validNeighbours (int x,int y, ArrayList visited) {
            ArrayList valid = new ArrayList();

            if((x+1 <= xRows) && !visited.contains(((x+1)*10)+y) ) {
                valid.add(((x+1)*10)+y);
            }
            if((x-1 >= 0) && !visited.contains(((x-1)*10)+y) ) {
                valid.add(((x-1)*10)+y);
            }
            if((y+1 <= yColumns) && !visited.contains(x*10+y+1) ) {
                valid.add(x*10+y+1);
            }
            if((y-1 >= 0) && !visited.contains(x*10+y-1) ) {
                valid.add(x*10+y-1);
            }

            return valid;
        }

        static void pathify(int x,int y,  ArrayList alreadyVisited) {
            if(x == xRows && y == yColumns) {
                noOfPaths++;
            } else {
                alreadyVisited.add(x*10+y);
                ArrayList callAgain = new ArrayList();
                callAgain = validNeighbours(x,y,alreadyVisited);
                for (int t=0,temp; t<callAgain.size(); t++) {
                    temp=(int) callAgain.get(t);
                    pathify(temp/10, temp%10, alreadyVisited);
                }

            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {


            ArrayList alreadyVisited = new ArrayList();

            pathify(0, 0, alreadyVisited);

            System.out.println(noOfPaths);
        }

    }
```

Comment: a small sidenote, if you use generics as `List<Integer>` you wont need to typecast to `int` all day long and your code is getting more typesafe

Comment: will keep that in mind

Comment: You only modifying a copy of your array list not the actual arraylist.

Comment: I get `3` as the output, the code seems to work okay for me ... assuming that's the result you're expecting...

Comment: Answer for 1x1 grid is 2. For 2x2 it is 12. So there is a mistake. I debugged it and found "noOfPaths" static variable is not modified

Comment: Side note: If you're going from (0,0) to (4,4) your grid is (5x5).

Comment: @YogevLevy Take 1x1 grid to be a square. Then you have vertices {(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1) }. It has (1,1).

Comment: @NanduD ok, I get that (the naming of "rows" and "columns" confused me). To the question at hand - if you make noOfPaths not static, does it work for you? And - why should it be static anyway?

Comment: I did it in a single class ,so it had to be static. It will not work  by simply making noOfPaths non-static.I will put the methods in different class and check it.

Comment: @YogevLevyPoint noted.

Comment: @NanduD 2x2 = 4, and your example of a "1x1 grid" has 4 vertices.  So it's a lot more natural to call it 2x2.  I can understand why you might see it differently, but I think you're in a small minority here, and it's best to use terminology the majority of us understand in order to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in how you're handling `alreadyVisited`.  The first time `pathify` is called, this list will contain only the initial square (0,0), which is fine.  Here's the important part of your code:

```
            for (int t=0,temp; t<callAgain.size(); t++) {
                temp=(int) callAgain.get(t);
                pathify(temp/10, temp%10, alreadyVisited);
            }
```

You've found the neighbors of the initial cell.  Your code will pick the first neighbor; then it will find paths starting with that neighbor, and the recursive calls to `pathify` will add cells to `alreadyVisited`.

Now, after all the recursive calls come back, you're ready to find cells starting with the *second* neighbor of the initial cell.  But you have a problem: *`alreadyVisited` still has all the cells it's collected from the paths it found starting with the second neighbor.*  So you won't find all possible paths starting with the second neighbor; you won't find any path that includes *any* cell in *any* path you've previously found.  This isn't what you want, since you only want to avoid visiting the same cell in *each* path--you don't want to avoid visiting the same cell in all your previous paths.  (I simplified this a little bit.  In reality, the problem will start occurring deeper down the recursive stack, and you won't even find all the paths beginning with the first neighbor.)

When implementing a recursive algorithm, I've found that it's generally a bad idea to keep an intermediate data structure that is shared by recursive invocations that will be modified by those invocations.  In this case, that's the list `alreadyVisited`.  The problem is that when an invocation deeper down the stack modifies the structure, this affects invocations further up, because they will see the modifications after the deeper invocations return, which is basically data they need changing underneath them.  (I'm not talking about a collection that is used to hold a list of results, if the list is basically write-only.)  The way to avoid it here is that instead of adding to `alreadyVisited`, you could create a *clone* of this list and then add to it.  That way, a deeper invocation can be sure that it's not impacting the shallower invocations by changing their data.  That is, instead of

```
alreadyVisited.add(x*10+y);
```

write

```
alreadyVisited = [make a copy of alreadyVisited];
alreadyVisited.add(x*10+y);
```

The `add` will modify a new list, not the list that other invocations are using.  (Personally, I'd declare a new variable such as `newAlreadyVisited`, since I don't really like modifying parameters, for readability reasons.)

This may seem inefficient.  It will definitely use more memory (although the memory should be garbage-collectible pretty quickly).  But trying to share a data structure between recursive invocations is very, very difficult to do correctly.  It can be done if you're very careful about cleaning up the changes and restoring the structure to what it was when the method began.  That might be necessary if the structure is something like a large tree, making it unfeasible to copy for every invocation.  But it can take a lot of skill to make things work.

**EDIT:** I tested it and it appears to work: 12 if `xRows`=`yColumns`=2, 8512 if both are 4 (is that correct?).  Another approach: instead of copying the list, I tried

```
alreadyVisited.remove((Object)(x*10+y));
```

at the end of the method (`(Object)` is needed so that Java doesn't think you're removing at an index) and that gave me the same results.  If you do that, you'll make sure that `alreadyVisited` is the same when `pathify` returns as it was when it started.  But I want to emphasize that I don't recommend this "cleanup" approach unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks. I will stick with the memory intensive one and try to solve it , thanks to you, your knowledge